# Why I can open serial via screen but cannot open via minicom?

Tags: gnu-screen, minicom

I have an arduino communication via Serial port at `/dev/ttyACM0` and I can open it via screen:

```
$ screen /dev/ttyACM0 115200
```

But for some reason I have no privileges to open it via minicom:

```
$ minicom /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200
minicom: cannot open /dev/tty8: Άρνηση πρόσβασης
```

My user is in `dialout` group:

```
$ groups
pcmagas adm dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare wireshark kvm docker
$ whoami
pcmagas
```

Any ideas why? AFAIK arduino uses an FTDI chip and the module used by kernel is `cdc_acm` one:

```
$ udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/ttyACM0
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/tty/ttyACM0
N: ttyACM0
S: android0
S: serial/by-id/usb-Arduino__www.arduino.cc__0043_7533131313335170A061-if00
S: serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.0
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/serial/by-id/usb-Arduino__www.arduino.cc__0043_7533131313335170A061-if00 /dev/android0 /dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/ttyACM0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/tty/ttyACM0
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_MM_CANDIDATE=1
E: ID_MODEL=0043
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=0043
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=Uno R3 (CDC ACM)
E: ID_MODEL_ID=0043
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_3_1_0
E: ID_PCI_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Serial bus controller
E: ID_PCI_INTERFACE_FROM_DATABASE=XHCI
E: ID_PCI_SUBCLASS_FROM_DATABASE=USB controller
E: ID_REVISION=0001
E: ID_SERIAL=Arduino__www.arduino.cc__0043_7533131313335170A061
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=7533131313335170A061
E: ID_TYPE=generic
E: ID_USB_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Communications
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=cdc_acm
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:020201:0a0000:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR=Arduino__www.arduino.cc_
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Arduino\x20\x28www.arduino.cc\x29
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Arduino SA
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=2341
E: MAJOR=166
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=tty
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=9517655754
```

Though by passing the `-D` parameter into minicom does open:

```
minicom -D /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200
```

But I do not understand the reason why `-D` parameter is required. Is that because for the device `plugdev` group is used?

```
ll /dev/ttyACM0
crw-rw---- 1 root plugdev 166, 0 Αυγ  11 13:05 /dev/ttyACM0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`minicom` does not actually accept a device name on the command line without the `-D` option. If a non-option argument is specified, it will be used as a suffix for the Minicom configuration file.

If you specify `minicom /dev/ttyACM0`, it actually attempts to read a configuration file at either `/etc/minicom/minirc./dev/ttyACM0` or `~/.minirc./dev/ttyACM0`.

The intended use is something like this:

1. Start Minicom in setup mode, giving the desired name for your new configuration, e.g. `minicom -s arduino`. Optionally, you could use other options to specify the port and speed here, e.g. `minicom -D /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200 -s arduino`.
2. Go to the `Serial port setup` menu and change the "Serial Device" (item `A`) to `/dev/ttyACM0` and the BPS/Parity/Bits (item `E`) to 115200 8N1 (or whatever your device requires. Also set the hardware and software flow control (items `F` and `G`) as required.
3. Press Esc to return to the configuration menu, and select `Save setup as arduino`, then select `Exit from Minicom`
4. Now Minicom is configured, and you can start it using the port, speed and flow control settings you saved, with just `minicom arduino`.

If you do the configuration as root, the settings will be saved to `/etc/minicom/minirc.arduino`, and will be available to all users on the system (assuming `/etc/minicom` is readable to all); if you do it as a regular user, the settings will be saved to `~/.minirc.arduino` and will be available for that user account only.

Answer (score 0):

The man page for minicom explains the `-D` command-line option:

```
-D, --device
        Specify the device, overriding the value given in the configuration file.
```

`minicom` is a program that's heavily governed by its config file, and on your machine the config file didn't have an entry for `/dev/ttyACM0`.  The `screen` program can take the name of a device on its command line, but `minicom` expects the device to be specified in a different way unless you provide the right command-line option.  In this case `-D`.